# Dell Latitude 5590 - How to scroll with central button

Tags: dell, mouse-scroll, trackpoint

I have a Dell Latitude 5590 with Ubuntu 18.04 installed alongside Windows 10 in dual-boot.

Inside Windows, I can **scroll pages by holding the central button and moving the trackpoint**.

Inside **Ubuntu**, such scrolling feature **doesn't work**.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

(by the way, the same scrolling feature works on Ubuntu 18.04 with Lenovo Thinkpads)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer and solved the problem.
I edited the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf and I changed the following section (the one having **pointer** identifier), adding the two **Option** lines:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
        Option "ScrollButton" "2"
EndSection
```

Comment: This also worked for my Latitude 4790; thank you!

Comment: This worked on Latitude 5491 :)

Comment: Dell Latitude 5590 and Debian Stretch - also works.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for my Latitude 5401 only after changing the Ubuntu desktop from Wayland (default) to X11. Took me a while to figure this out.